# How to prove $\sum_{k=n}^{2n} k = 3 \sum_{k=1}^n k $ with complete induction?

Tags: induction

I was trying to prove this. Have problems to "pull apart" the first sum to put it down to the induction base (n - 1). Base and step are otherwise clear. Could you please help me?

Comment: Maybe you could type out the argument you tried so we can see how you might complete the proof.

Comment: Don't use induction for this.

Comment: I have to...

Tried: 
Base: $n=1$ : $$\sum_{k=1}^{2} k = 1 + 2 = 3 * 1 = 3 \sum_{k=1}^1 k$$
Step: from $n-1$ to $n$: we know that $$\sum_{k=n-1}^{2(n-1)} k = 3 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k$$

$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n} k = \sum_{k=n-1}^{2(n-1)} k + 2n-1 + 3n + n = ?????$$

Otherwise I thought that I need something like $$3 \sum_{k=1}^n k = 3 (\sum_{k=1}^(n-1) k + n) = 3 sum_{k=1}^(n-1) k + 3n$$

Comment: Does it help knowing that $$ \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$?

Comment: Hint: For the induction step: $\sum_{n+1}^{2n+2} k=\sum_{n}^{2n}  k +\left((2n+1)+(2n+2)-n\right)=\sum_n^{2n}k +3(n+1)$.

Comment: André! Too simple :D THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!

Comment: Also, you do not need complete induction - regular induction from n-1 to n works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do an induction proof, using the hint of @André Nicolas :

- **Initialisation :** For $n=1$ you have $\sum_{k=1}^2k=3=3\cdot\sum_{k=1}^1k.$
- **Heredity :** Suppose the result is true for $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ and let's show it is true for $n+1.$ You have that
  $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2(n+1)}k=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}k+2n+1+2n+2-n=3\cdot\sum_{k=1}^nk+3n+3=3\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k$$ and you get your result.

Comment: That you very much - it's much easier to use $n+1$ instead of $n-1$ version...

Comment: @isindia : You're welcome !

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation:

Suppose
$\sum_{k=n-1}^{2(n-1)} k - 3 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k
= 0
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=n}^{2n} k - 3 \sum_{k=1}^{n} k
&=(\sum_{k=n-1}^{2(n-1)} k-(n-1)+2n-1+2n - 3 (\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k+n)\\
&=\sum_{k=n-1}^{2(n-1)} k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k+
(-(n-1)+2n-1+2n - 3 k)\\
&=0+0\\
&=0\\
\end{array}
$

and we are done.